# jquery table sorter with a combination of different kind of data not working

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using [jquery table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and it was working nicely for me. Yesterday, I got to see an issue with the columns which have a combination of data (string and date) and the plugin does not sort these kind of columns. This column actually displays comments inserted by a user with the date, when it was inserted.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out my [fork of the tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) plugin... it automatically includes alphanumeric sorting, which was not included in the original version. Maybe this will help fix the problem you are having with mixed data. If not, then you might need to write a custom parser to extract the specific data from the table cell by which the column is to be sorted.

If the above suggestions do not help, then I would ask you to please share an example of the HTML you are using and how you expect it to sort.